# cant plot derivate from differential equation

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

Suppose this code in Mathematica:

```
w[w1_] := NDSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] == 2, y'[0] == 0, y[0] == w1},y[x], {x, 0, 30}];
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[{y[x], y'[x]} /. w[w1]], {x, 0, 30}], {w1, -2, 3}]
```

The code works this way: A slidebar (in Manipulate) controls one initial condition (value of y[0]) of differential equation saved in variable w and when it is changed, the solution is plotted. This works fine, but I have a problem with plotting the first derivative of the solution (y'[x]). Instead of a function graph there is just simply blank space and nothing is plotted, even I checked it in Mathematica help, where the example code

```
s = NDSolve[{y''[x] + Sin[y[x]] y[x] == 0, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 30}]
Plot[Evaluate[{y[x], y'[x], y''[x]} /. s], {x, 0, 30},PlotStyle -> Automatic]
```

works. Does anybody know where's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem, it is just in NDSolve it is needed to write

```
w[w1_] := NDSolve[{y''[x] + y[x] == 2, y'[0] == 0, y[0] == w1},y, {x, 0, 30}]
```

y instead of y[x] and everything works.